Does Allah sees us everytime?
Assalamualaikum! This question is hitting my mind from few days that I believe Allah sees us everytime and is with us no matter what are we doing. So Does Allah also see us like when we are in bathrooms doing shower and all and when two people interact with each other.. Allah is very modest.. I'm afraid that if I'll get sin for such thought..
(There is also a hadith that Hazrat Umer was so modest that he used to cover himself while bathing so Angles don't see him)

Simply put, yes, Allah sees us at all times, and even knows what we are thinking at all times. See Quran verse 50:16.
